# Why does 10 not display when I List Ascii Converter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm experiencing a strange "issue" with my program... when I run it, select the second option and type "list" my computer boops and this happens:

```
List:
1 = ☺
2 = ☻
3 = ♥
4 = ♦
5 = ♣
6 = ♠
7 =
8 =
9 =
10 =

11 = ♂
12 = ♀
13 =
14 = ♫
15 = ☼
```

This is my code:

```
#In This Program We Will Be Converting ASCII To It's Numerical Counterpart And Visa-Versa...

no = 0
on = 0

lo = 0
ol = 0

print ("Welcome to the ASCII/Numerical-Counterpart Converter!\nPlease Select One Of The Following:\n1: ASCII to Number.\n2: Number to ASCII")

inp = raw_input(":")

if inp == "1":
    inp1 = raw_input("Please Enter ASCII Character(s)\n:")
    no = len(inp1)

    while no != on:

        print inp1[on], "=", ord(inp1[on])

        on += 1

    exit()

if inp == "2":
    inp2 = raw_input("Please Enter Numerical Character(s), or \"list\" (Use Spaces For Multiple Integers)\n:")
    wall = ""

    if inp2 == "list":
        print "\nList:"
        al = 1
        do = 128
        inp2 = ""
        while do != al:
            wall = str(al)
            if al == 127:
                inp2 += wall
            else:
                inp2 += wall + " "
            al += 1
    lo = inp2.split(" ")
    loo = len(lo)

    while loo != ol:

        out = lo[ol]
        outie = int(out)
        if outie > 127:
            print "Sorry! Can't Convert Numbers Larger Than 127..."
            exit()
        print lo[ol], "=", str(unichr(outie))

        ol += 1
```

If anyone can tell me why it's doing this I would be very grateful... I have no idea what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASCII characters below 32 have special meanings: ASCII 7 is a "bell" character (which is displayed as a beep), ASCII 9 is a tab character, ASCII 10 is a line feed, ASCII 13 is a carriage return character. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII char of 10 is a LineFeed. So it is displayed as new Line as you can see in your Output.